# Move files in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, move, mv

I want a script that is able to read the content of a text file which contains folder names and moves the folders from their directory to a specific folder. Here is my script:

```
     #!/bin/bash
     for i in $(cat /folder/collected/folders.txt)
      do
       mv /fromfilelocation/$i /folder/Collected/
      done
```

This script is partly working as it copies only the last folder in the text file, as for the other folders it gives the error "not possible: data or directory not found" But the folder is there and according to the error the folder directory is correctly displayed.

What should I do in order to make it work correctly ??

Comment: does the file folders.txt contains full paths or relative paths?

Comment: Are there spaces or special characters in your filenames?

Comment: here's a one liner to test "cat /folder/collected/folders.txt | while read each; do mv /fromfilelocation/$each /folder/Collected; done;"

Comment: @hovanessyan it did not work, it gives the same error, it reads the wolder name correctly but at the end there is '$'\r'. example /fromfilelocation/foldername'$'\r'. and the folder.txt contains only file names and i also tried it with full path it did not work

Comment: @Thomas no spaces or special charactars

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for sample in `awk '{print $1}' All_bins.txt`
    do mv "$sample" All_Good_Bins
    done
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use while loop instead

```
while read i; do
  mv fromfilelocation/"$i" /folder/Collected/
done </folder/collected/folders.txt
```

Comment: Quote your variables

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla I tried the while loop the way you said, but it is copying the whole directory and not the folders inside it